# Master page header not showing in BIRT report

Tags: birt, spagobi

I have a problem with BIRT. I created a report with the relative Master Page, and I am trying to export it in PDF format.

While I am able to see the Master Page header and footer when I look at the report preview with the web viewer, I am not able to see the header in the PDF export of my report (but I see the footer).

In the header properties the `Hide element` checkbox is unchecked.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard without the XML, but you can check this:

First I would check the header height in the MasterPage properties. Does is really fit what you are showing in the header? If not sure, replace header by a simple text element and try again.... The web preview tends to get to just scale to fit, while the PDF has a more strict interpretation of set sizes.

or

There are ways to manipulate the properties on 'runtime'. You could check your XML for scripts with code like this:

```
reportContext.getOutputFormat() == "pdf"
```

Or parts of it. Perhaps there is clue.

Comment: You should also think of "show header on first" / "show footer on last"

Comment: True, but @Andrea lalenti mentioned seeing a header in de preview, so I guess this is set correct.